# using requestPathInvalidChars in asp.net application

Tags: c#, web-config

I would like to allow a page on my website to allow & and . charecters in my website. I found out that this is possible with putting requestPathInvalidChars in your webconfig. looking around on the web I did not find any good examples on how to accomplish this. How do I allow those specified char on my site? thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just set it to blank:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
</system.web>
```

but I also urge you to read [Scott's article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) about this.